# Infinite dimension left shift operator over the complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let $S$ be the left shift operator over the infinite complex vector field. Show that 
$$
\text{null}(S-I)^3=\text{span}\{(1,1,1,1,\ldots),(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots),(0,1,4,9,16,25,.....)\}.
$$

To start I found that $(S-I)^3$ is defined by 
$$
(S-I)^3(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,\ldots)=(x_1-3x_2+3x_3-x_4,x_2-3x_3+3x_4-x_5,\ldots)
$$
Which defines the recursive relationship
$x_{i+3}=x_i-3x_{i+1}+3x_{i+2}$

Which equals zero if in the null.
Each of the three vectors satisfy the above equation, but how do I prove that they span? I.e that nothing else belongs in the null.

Answer (score 0):

Given the recursive relationship you found, the first three components of a vector in the null space define unambigously all the others. On the other hand, the first three components can be chosen arbitrarily, and completing the vector according to the recursive rule will still put it in the null space.

Which is just a long way of saying that the null space is really $C^3$ in disguise. Focus on the first three components and throw away the rest. You have three vectors already in this space: $(1,1,1), (0,1,2), (0,1,4)$. Figure out whether they span the whole space.